# php openssl signed string not getting verified by Win CryptoAPI

Tags: rsa, openssl

I am signing some text using php openssl and trying to verify it in the windows app using CryptoApi but validation always fails. Please help me out.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

$data = "data that is to be hashed and signed.";


$private_key = <<<EOD
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIIBOgIBAAJBANDiE2+Xi/WnO+s120NiiJhNyIButVu6zxqlVzz0wy2j4kQVUC4Z
    RZD80IY+4wIiX2YxKBZKGnd2TtPkcJ/ljkUCAwEAAQJAL151ZeMKHEU2c1qdRKS9
    sTxCcc2pVwoAGVzRccNX16tfmCf8FjxuM3WmLdsPxYoHrwb1LFNxiNk1MXrxjH3R
    6QIhAPB7edmcjH4bhMaJBztcbNE1VRCEi/bisAwiPPMq9/2nAiEA3lyc5+f6DEIJ
    h1y6BWkdVULDSM+jpi1XiV/DevxuijMCIQCAEPGqHsF+4v7Jj+3HAgh9PU6otj2n
    Y79nJtCYmvhoHwIgNDePaS4inApN7omp7WdXyhPZhBmulnGDYvEoGJN66d0CIHra
    I2SvDkQ5CmrzkW5qPaE2oO7BSqAhRZxiYpZFb5CI
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    EOD;
    $public_key = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBANDiE2+Xi/WnO+s120NiiJhNyIButVu6
zxqlVzz0wy2j4kQVUC4ZRZD80IY+4wIiX2YxKBZKGnd2TtPkcJ/ljkUCAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOD;

$binary_signature = "";

// At least with PHP 5.2.2 / OpenSSL 0.9.8b (Fedora 7)
// there seems to be no need to call openssl_get_privatekey or similar.
// Just pass the key as defined above
openssl_sign($data, $binary_signature, $private_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);

// Check signature
$ok = openssl_verify($data, $binary_signature, $public_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
echo $binary_signature;
    echo "\n";
    echo strlen($binary_signature);
echo "\n";
echo strlen($public_key);

$binary_signature="ÅâŸoÀÞü¸IOT6ê¿›¹ý“´Šæ¸Ûà$,&†-X÷bË`‡0¥u«CAÚNgÏ¼‡Êû`Sî";
echo "check #1: ";
echo sha1($data);
    if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "signature ok (as it should be)\n";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "bad (there's something wrong)\n";
} else {
    echo "ugly, error checking signature\n";
}

$ok = openssl_verify('tampered'.$data, $binary_signature, $public_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
echo "check #2: ";
if ($ok == 1) {
        echo "ERROR: Data has been tampered, but signature is still valid! Argh!\n";
    } elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "bad signature (as it should be, since data has beent tampered)\n";
} else {
    echo "ugly, error checking signature\n";
}

?>
```

C++ Code:

```
HCRYPTPROV hProv;
    BYTE *pbBuffer= (BYTE *)"data that is to be hashed and signed.";
    DWORD dwBufferLen = strlen((char *)pbBuffer)+1;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash;
    HCRYPTKEY hPubKey;
    BYTE *pbKeyBlob;
    // signature from php script
    BYTE pbSignature[128] = "BõŸûëN2¸GõÂÌ_;3µÜåJˆLôMÐh’*¡mø&·À„<ááø‡–e…ÎJ‡B¥tyƒ¥Óþ'N]Ù";
DWORD dwSigLen = strlen((char *)pbSignature);

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------


    char           pemPubKey[2048] = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBANDiE2+Xi/WnO+s120NiiJhNyIButVu6zxqlVzz0wy2j4kQVUC4ZRZD80IY+4wIiX2YxKBZKGnd2TtPkcJ/ljkUCAwEAAQ==-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    //int            readLen;
    unsigned char           derPubKey[2048];
    DWORD         derPubKeyLen = 2048;
    CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO *publicKeyInfo;
    DWORD            publicKeyInfoLen;
    //HANDLE         hFile;


    if ( !CryptStringToBinaryA( pemPubKey, 0, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER, derPubKey, &derPubKeyLen, NULL, NULL ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "CryptStringToBinary failed. Err: %d\n", GetLastError() );
    }
    /*
     * Decode from DER format to CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO
     */
    if ( !CryptDecodeObjectEx( X509_ASN_ENCODING, X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO, derPubKey, derPubKeyLen, 
                               CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG, NULL, &publicKeyInfo, &publicKeyInfoLen ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "CryptDecodeObjectEx 1 failed. Err: %p\n", GetLastError() );
        return -1;
    }

    // Acquire a cryptographic provider context handle.

    if(CryptAcquireContext(
        &hProv, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        PROV_RSA_FULL, 
        CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) 
    {
        printf("CSP context acquired.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Error during CryptAcquireContext.");
    }

    if ( CryptImportPublicKeyInfo( hProv, MY_ENCODING_TYPE, publicKeyInfo, &hPubKey ) )
    {
        printf("The key has been imported.\n");

    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Public key import failed.");
    }
    if(publicKeyInfo)
        LocalFree( publicKeyInfo );
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Create a new hash object.

    if(CryptCreateHash(
        hProv, 
        CALG_SHA1, 
        0, 
        0, 
        &hHash)) 
    {
        printf("The hash object has been recreated. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Error during CryptCreateHash.");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Compute the cryptographic hash of the buffer.

    if(CryptHashData(
        hHash, 
        pbBuffer, 
        dwBufferLen, 
        0)) 
    {
        printf("The new hash has been created.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        MyHandleError("Error during CryptHashData.");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Validate the digital signature.

    if(CryptVerifySignature(
        hHash, 
        pbSignature, 
        dwSigLen, 
        hPubKey,
        NULL, 
        0)) 
    {
        printf("The signature has been verified.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Signature not validated!\n");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Free memory to be used to store signature.

    /*if(pbSignature)
        free(pbSignature);*/

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Destroy the hash object.

    if(hHash) 
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Release the provider handle.

    if(hProv) 
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems on the C++ side:

When calculating the size of the buffer to be hashed:

```
DWORD dwBufferLen = strlen((char *)pbBuffer)+1;
```

you're including the terminating `\0` character (which is not included when hashing the data in PHP). This should be:

```
DWORD dwBufferLen = strlen((char *)pbBuffer);
```

The signature data in the C++ code in your question isn't the same data as produced by the PHP script. This could just be the way StackOverflow has rendered it, but it could also be your code. You should use the actual hex bytes of the signature, rather than a "stringified" form, since the data could easily be corrupted depending on the particular encoding used to save your source file.

Finally, you should read the innocuous-looking "Remarks" section for [`CryptVerifySignature`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381097.aspx) which notes that the native crypto methods use little-endian byte order. If you reverse the bytes of the signature, you'll find that it verifies correctly.

Comment: thanks for the reply actually i got it working using std::string for signature and ofcourse reversing the signature